# Adding Count Column in sql query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have two table called Production and Chart as below.

**Production**

```
Name Layer
CDV  TSK
CDV  USV
M1   OSK
```

**Chart**

```
Name
L1_CDV_TSK
L1_CDV_TSK
L1_M1_OSK
```

I have to produce output like this:

```
Name Layer Count
CDV  TSK    2
CDV  USV    0
M1   OSK    1

// bse L1_CDV_TKK and L1_M1_OSK are in the Charttable.
```

How could I write a SQL query to achieve this?

This is my attempt, but it cannot see every row in the `Prodution` table

```
Select 
    p.Name, p.layer, Count(*) as test
from 
    Production p, Chart c 
where 
    c.chartname like '%'+ p.name+'_'+p.layer + '%'
group by 
    p.Name, p.layer
```

Please advise. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select p.Name,p.layer,Count(c.chartname) as test
from Production p
left join Chart c on c.chartname like '%'+ p.name+'_'+p.layer + '%'
group by p.Name,p.layer
```

EDIT :

think you have a typo in your "Chart" list, or I don't understand the result you want... (TSK, TKK)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select p.Name,p.layer,Count(*) as test
from Production p
left join Chart c on c.chartname like '%'+ p.name+'_'+p.layer + '%'
group by p.Name,p.layer
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to learn new join syntax:

```
Select p.Name, p.layer,Count(*) as test
from Production p join
     Chart c
     on c.chartname like '%'+ p.name+'_'+p.layer + '%'
group by p.Name, p.layer
```

Second, you are filtering out the one with the count of zero.

To get what you want, try:

```
Select p.Name, p.layer,
       sum(case when c.chartname like '%'+ p.name+'_'+p.layer + '%' then 1 else 0 end) as test
from Production p cross join
     Chart c
group by p.Name, p.layer
```